# Lazily retrieve an array used as IEnumerable

Tags: c#

I have access to an API that exposes an array of `T`, i.e. there is a signature

```
T[] Get();
```

I am creating an API that performs calculations on `T`s and produces `T2`. Each call to `Get()` is expensive, and each projection from `T` to `T2` is expensive. I may not need all `T2`s, and so I would like to expose:

```
IEnumerable<T2> GetProjected();
```

Now, I realize there's nothing I can do to make `Get()` lazy. I will need to retrieve the entire array. However, I would like to be able to call `GetProjected()` and get an `IEnumerable<T2>` without it immediately causing `Get()` to be called. In other words, the following two implementations are bad:

```
public IEnumerable<T2> GetProjected()
{
    var items = _api.Get(); // bad!

    return items.Select(t => ProjectToT2(t));
}

public IEnumerable<T2> GetProjected2()
{
    var items = new Lazy<IEnumerable<T>(() => _api.Get());

    return items
        .Value // bad again!
        .Select(t => ProjectToT2(t));
}
```

You may see where I'm going with this. How do I expose an `IEnumerable<T2>` without causing an immediate call to `Get()`? Do I have to implement a custom `IEnumerator<T2>` and `IEnumerable<T2>` pair?

Comment: Explain why you want this. Do you want to keep the IEnumerable ready for enumerating at a later time, only then calling Get()? Make it an iterator method or an Action?

Comment: Yes - I want it available for enumerating at a later time, and I don't want the consumer to have to worry that anything is being evaluated when `GetProjected` is called. That's one reason. Another is that the whole job is cancellable, and this may occur at intermediary places. I realize it's odd, but I really feel that you as a consumer should be able to trust that retrieving an `IEnumerable` won't lead to a bunch of expensive evaluation.

Comment: @TheGeneral It's _not_ enumerated. It's enumerable. Just because I have something that's enumerable doesn't mean I immediately want to enumerate it.

Comment: _"I really feel that you as a consumer should be able to trust that retrieving an IEnumerable won't lead to a bunch of expensive evaluation"_ - retrieving or building it, doesn't. Enumerating it does. You can build the most complex Entity Framework query, it you don't enumerate the results, the database isn't hit. This isn't true for your code, as it calls `Get()`.

Comment: Decompile `Get` and rewrite it to return `IEnumerable`

Comment: @CodeMaster Yes, that's exactly my point and why I'm asking. It's not true for my code. `Get()` is called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an iterator method:

```
public IEnumerable<T2> GetProjected()
{   
   var results = api.Get()
        .Select(t => ProjectToT2(t));

   foreach(var x in results) 
   {
        yield return x;
   }
}
```

You can't get around the array being retrieved in one complete chunk because of the signature of `Get()`, but this way it will only be called if you enumerate the result of `GetProjected()`, e.g. if you call `ToArray()` on it, but not with `Select()` or `Where`.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but how is this different to `return items.Value.Select(t => ProjectToT2(t));`? Why do you iterate `results` in that method, since it doesn't seem to add any value?

Comment: This is still evaluating the `Lazy<T>` immediately which is the problem.

Comment: @John @DavidG Since it's an iterator method with `yield`, the body of the method doesn't get executed until it is enumerated.

Comment: @John The OP asked: "How do I expose an `IEnumerable<T2>` without causing an immediate call to `Get()`?" This is the answer. (I'm not claiming that there's lot of benefit in doing that - there isn't enough context to judge.)

Comment: @MoB. its not about lazily returning items from the collection, but rather returning the whole array returned by Get lazily, as far as i can comprehend. So op should return a `new Lazy<IEnumerable<T2>(() => api.Get().ConvertAllToType2())` but instead wants it to be an ienumerable<t2> if that makes sense...

Comment: @MoB. @John is correct. Your implementation causes an immediate call to `Get()`. The `Select` is simply projecting the result you've retrieved. It is equivalent to my bad implementation.

Comment: @MoB. I was being dim, since OP hadn't defined `Get()` and in my head I was thinking that was already returning an `IEnumerable<something>`. Sorry. It has been a long day. 

Comment: @AlexanderHøst No, it doesn't immediately execute `Get()`. Try it.

Comment: @AlexanderHøst No, Mo is right. It shouldn't execute `Get()` until you start iterating.

Comment: Huh. I stand corrected. You're right @MoB.!

Comment: @CodeMaster I think it's getting downvoted because at first glance it looks like `Get()` is being immediately called, but of course, with a `yield` a state machine is created.